# How can I add a where clause to a Laravel relation?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class purchase_order extends Model
{
    protected $table = "purchase_order";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function commodities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commodities::class, 'purchase_order_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Now I need to add one more condition to `commodities()` method. Actually I need to say it return `commodities` that have this `where('commodities.invoiced', 1)`. How can I add this where clause to the relation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach for this would be to add a query scope of `invoiced()` to your `Commodities` model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes

So on your `Commodities` model you could add:

```
public function scopeInvoiced($query){
    return $query->where('invoiced', 1);
}
```

then call this with `Commodities->invoiced();`

Comment: Currently I use it like this `purchase_order::with("commodities")`. In your case, how can I use it using `with` ?

Comment: $purchase_orders = purchase_order::with([
    'commodities' => function ($query) {
        $query->invoiced();
    }
]);

Comment: Either create a different relation that calls `invoiced()` or do it inline as @Davit says.

Comment: And where is `invoiced()` function defined?

Comment: @MartinAJ `invoiced()` is your scope, it will hit the `scopeInvoiced()` function, can read more in the link Joe provided

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but with reference to the relations table like so:

```
public function commodities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(commodities::class, 'purchase_order_id', 'id')
        ->where('commodities.invoiced', 1);
}
```

When the query is being built, it accounts for the `commodities.invoiced` where query as well

Ref: https://laraveldaily.com/filter-eloquent-relationships-fly-need/